# List view web part hides last 2 items in a filtered view

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view, sharepoint-list-filter

Seeing a really odd phenomenon when I filter a list view either using the column's filter by property or using dynamic filtering with a connected web part. The filtered view should show about 30 or so items but the last 2 don't appear.

What's odd is if I inspect the page with dev tools OR if I drag my mouse below the last item, the missing items appear.
If I zoom the page in a little, they appear.
They also appear fine on the native list view page (ie not using a web part).

I'm used to weird bugs in Sharepoint, but this is a headscratcher.

[image: screen grab]

Comment: Can you test this in a different browser and see if the issue remains? Also check the HTML structure, there might be some information there on why this bug is happening.

Comment: Same on other browsers - this is a list connected to another list for filtering, and other filters don't seem to have the issue, just this one. The html is generated by Sharepoint and looks ok.

Comment: It seems like the problem is specific to the particular filter you’re using, as you mentioned that other filters don’t seem to have the issue. It might be a rendering issue, especially since the items appear when you inspect the page with dev tools. Can you provide some more information to help with this question: the filter you are using, the list setup, any error messages you see, and the specific item details.

Comment: It's a connected list filter - so one list configured to filter another list based on value of column. Both lists are simple, and there's only about 380 items in the target list. Definitely a rendering issue most likely some flawed javascript Msft is using in the lazy load. They're investigating it but never seem to resolve bugs reported by users.

Comment: Sometimes, leading or trailing spaces in the values being filtered can cause issues.
Although you mentioned there are only about 380 items in your target list, it might still be worth reindexing the list. `Settings > Advanced Settings > Reindex List`. You might want to try disconnecting and then reconnecting the web parts. Compare the values that work with the ones that don’t to see if there are any noticeable differences. In some cases, having too many web parts on a page can cause issues. Try removing some web parts to see if that resolves the issue. Try these and let me know if they help.

Comment: Good suggestions - but didn't help. Noting too that the missing items DO show up when the list is unfiltered.